# VB.net setting hidden field value to Data table column names conditionally

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a set of asp hidden field controls which I wish to set the values according to my data tables column names, the amount of columns returned differ, so I am setting the unused hidden fields to 0 if not used. Below is what I've attempted so far just struggling to set the correct hidden field accordingly.

VB-

```
            Dim dt As DataTable
            Dim ds As New DataSet()
            ds = Getdata(4)
            dt = ds.Tables(0)

            Dim ColCnt As String = dt.Columns.Count 'Current ColCnt is 3
            For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                Select Case ColCnt
                    Case 2
                        hxValue.Value = column.ColumnName 'set to 1st Column Name
                        hxValue1.Value = 0 'Not used
                        hyValue.Value = column.ColumnName 'Set To 2nd Column Name
                    Case 3
                        hxValue.Value = column.ColumnName 'set to 1st Column Name
                        hxValue1.Value = column.ColumnName 'set to 2nd Column Name
                        hyValue.Value = column.ColumnName 'set to 3rd Column Name
                End Select
            Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I don't think you need a `For Each` loop :

```
Dim ColCnt As Int = dt.Columns.Count 'Current ColCnt is 3    
Select Case ColCnt
    Case 2
        hxValue.Value = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName 'set to 1st Column Name
        hxValue1.Value = 0 'Not used
        hyValue.Value = dt.Columns[1].ColumnName 'Set To 2nd Column Name
    Case 3
        hxValue.Value = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName 'set to 1st Column Name
        hxValue1.Value = dt.Columns[1].ColumnName 'set to 2nd Column Name
        hyValue.Value = dt.Columns[2].ColumnName 'set to 3rd Column Name
End Select
```